# Vertices only showing with X-ray on

Tags: 3d-view, vertices

I am following the Donut Blender tutorial and when I duplicated the top half of the donut to make the icing the icing's vertices only show when I go into X-ray mode. I have deleted and reduplicated it but it continues to only show in x-ray mode. The donut itself works perfectly fine
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe what we see in Edit mode is a duplication of your object, and you've hidden the vertices of the selected one, try an Alt H to unhide

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, but I simply forgot to turn off the solidify modifier being visible. Feel real dumb for not realizing sooner.